# How Can I Guarantee That My Android App is executed at least once before it is updated?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to be able to detect the first run of my app before it has been updated by Google Play. (Trust me, this is a legitimate scenario.) Is there a way for me to keep Google Play/Android from updating the app before it has been run at least once?

Comment: If you can change the App version number dynamically then you can keep the Google Play Store away from updating your app !

Comment: Yeah, perhaps update the app yourself?

Comment: I don't think so, afaik the app update process is independent and does not generate any app lifecycle event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with an engineer from Google. There is not currently any means to absolutely guarantee that an app is run before it is updated by the Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 apps, one that triggers the installation of the other via Intent. That way, you are sure the first one was run before installing the second.

Comment: But this will not fully fill the real use case! I mean, I need to post 2 APK in play store !